# Authenticate user through GitHub API using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, github

I have to authenticate a user through the GitHub API in Ruby to be able to create a private repository.

The [GitHub manual](http://develop.github.com/p/general.html) shows how to do it with curl.

Could someone show me how to do it with a Ruby gem like [rest-client](http://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) or [octopussy](http://github.com/pengwynn/octopussy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(:login => 'someguy', :token => 'sometoken123b1i3')
client.create(:name=>'foobar', :description=>'Foo Bar', :homepage=> 'http://example.com', :public=>false)
```

http://github.com/pengwynn/octokit/blob/master/lib/octokit/client.rb#L198

Answer (score 0):

using RestClient, first you need to create a resource, then use that to post the JSON data defining the repo metadata:

```
my_resource = RestClient::Resource.new( "https://api.github.com", :user => "username", :password => "123456" )
my_resource["/user/repos"].post( { :name => "new-repo", :description => "this is a new repo", :public => true }.to_json )
```

See http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/ for details on the API